# Hibernate 5.2 schema validation error with BOOLEAN in MariaDB

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, mariadb

I create a Spring Boot 1.5 project using Spring JPA, Hibernate 5.2. I created the schema setting:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto: create
```

Then I stopped my application and I restarted the app with the value:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto: validate
```

I've a bean like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(uniqueConstraints = { @UniqueConstraint(name = "account_username", columnNames = { "username" }) })
public class Account extends AbstractEntity implements CustomUserDetail {

    @NotBlank
    @Username
    @Column(nullable = false/* , unique = true */)
    private String username;

    private String password;

    private Instant lastPasswordUpdate;

    @NotNull
    @Column(nullable = false)
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private AccountType type = AccountType.USER;


    @NotNull
    @Column(nullable = false, columnDefinition = "BOOLEAN default true")
    private boolean enabled = true;

    @Audited
    @Size(min = 1)
    @Type(type = "json")
    @Column(columnDefinition = "json")
    private Roles[] roles = new Roles[] {};
```

The generated table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `account` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `createdBy` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `createdDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `lastModifiedBy` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lastModifiedDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `sid` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
  `version` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `enabled` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `lastPasswordUpdate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `roles` json DEFAULT NULL,
  `type` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `account_username` (`username`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UK_5fs2lcge9gnvs1seea2fwnwv5` (`sid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

When I start the application with `valitate` option I get this error:

```
 Caused by: org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: wrong column type encountered in column [enabled] in table [`Account`]; found [bit (Types#BIT)], but expecting [boolean default true (Types#BOOLEAN)]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaValidator.validateColumnType(AbstractSchemaValidator.java:159) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.12.Final.jar:5.2.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaValidator.validateTable(AbstractSchemaValidator.java:143) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.12.Final.jar:5.2.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.GroupedSchemaValidatorImpl.validateTables(GroupedSchemaValidatorImpl.java:42) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.12.Final.jar:5.2.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaValidator.performValidation(AbstractSchemaValidator.java:89) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.12.Final.jar:5.2.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaValidator.doValidation(AbstractSchemaValidator.java:68) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.12.Final.jar:5.2.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:191) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.12.Final.jar:5.2.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:72) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.12.Final.jar:5.2.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:313) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.12.Final.jar:5.2.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:452) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.12.Final.jar:5.2.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:889) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.12.Final.jar:5.2.12.Final]
```

That is quite weird since the original schema was created with the same exact configuration.

I used these connection properties and I'm using MariaDB 10.2.13 on Windows:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3310/rebus?useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC&tinyInt1isBit=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MariaDBDialect (with MariaDB53Dialect it's the same)
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
```

I tried the same configuration (with the option `transformedBitIsBoolean`) and drivers and dialect for Mysql 5.7 and I've not any issue.

Am I doing something wrong? How can I solve the problem without make my model dirty with custom types and leaving it clean as it is now?

======= UPDATES ============

Investigating and debugging into Hibernate's `AbstractSchemaValidator`, this is the line that is creating the problem:

```
boolean typesMatch = column.getSqlTypeCode( metadata ) == columnInformation.getTypeCode()
                || column.getSqlType( dialect, metadata ).toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT).startsWith( columnInformation.getTypeName().toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT) );
```

The type detected from `column.getSqlTypeCode( metadata )` is 16, instead type from `columnInformation.getTypeCode()` is -7. When I use Mysql the type is 16 on both sides.

Comment: Check, don't you have an additional column definition on getters?

Comment: @Andremoniy I created the bean. No I didn't add any other additional column definition.